# Screen itself larger than monitor at recommended res? Software solution? How to zoom out?

Tags: windows-10, display, external-display

I've started using a TV as a secondary display
My resolution is 1080p, but only about 980 of it is visible 100p of visual content seems to be behind the TV frame.

[image: Image description (for screen-reader software): only half of the start-menu icon is shown in this image because the other half is hiding behind the bottom-left corner of the monitor frame; also, only the bottom half of the taskbar is cut off by the frame.]

I'm wondering if there is a software that will 'zoom out' and bring the image back into frame (especially a software with low overhead)?

Comment: This is one of the hateful things about connecting a TV to a computer, they do not always faithfully display the image as intended because they either assume that what is coming in will always have a black border or their panel extends beyond the bezel and they end up zooming, shrinking or cropping in hardware. I've never gotten what I would consider a "good" image doing stuff in the computer, it's something you need to deal with at the TV end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look for a setting on your TV which will be called "Overscan" or something similar. You need to turn this off and you should be able to see the whole picture again.

Comment: Unless the Graphics control panel in Windows has an underscan slider. I've never seen one on Windows, but Mac does if it recognises it's connected to a TV rather than Monitor.

Comment: Alternatively many graphic cards support "underscan" or overscan via their drivers.  In the Nvidia Control Panel for example you can go to `Display` -> `Adjust Desktop Size and Position` and in that window is a `Size` tab where you can fix under oroverscan resizing. It would be preferred to fix the TV though. Some TVs might have this referred to as "game mode"

Comment: "back in the day" nvidia only offered overscan adjustment if plugged via HDMI (i.e. not dvi). Just in case this matters for the OP or People from the Future(tm)

Comment: Can't say this is the answer I want. ^^
Would love to see a software that accomplishes this.  I feel like it's something I could even possibly do in AHK or openGL... just create a window and render my desktop in the window.... 
But until there's a better answer, I have to say this one pushed my knowledge forward a lot.  Thanks for the useful vocab and hardware info.